# Conditional multinomial probability

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, multinomial-distribution

Given 7 experiments and 3 types of successes, with probabilities $p_1, p_2, p_3$ respectively and $p_1+ p_2+ p_3 = 1$ we'll denote:

$$X_i = \text{number of successes of type i}$$

I'm looking for $P(X_1 = 3 | X_3 \le 2)$

So by definition of conditional probability:

$$P(X_1 = 3 | X_3 \le 2) = \frac{P(X_1 = 3, X_3 \le 2)}{P(X_3 \le 2)} = $$

$$\frac{P(X_1 = 3, X_2 = 2, X_3 = 2) + P(X_1 = 3, X_2 = 3, X_3 = 1) + P(X_1 = 3, X_2 = 4, X_3 = 0)}{P(X_3 = 2) + P(X_3 = 1) + P(X_3 = 0)}$$

We know that $(X_1, X_2, X_3) \sim{Multi(7, p_1, p_2, p_3)}$

And $X_i \sim{Bin(7, p_i)}$

So from here we just use the formulas.

My question is if this could be simplified, or is there an immediate formula for $(X_i | X_j \le x_j)$ ?

Comment: Math mode isn't intended for italicizing text; as you can see here, it yields the wrong spacing for that. Usually text is italicized by enclosing it in asterisks. If you want to italicize text within math mode, you can use `\mathit{...}`. In the present case, there doesn't seem to be a need to italicize the text; in that case you can use `\text{...}` to include roman text in math mode.

Comment: My vote is No, there is no simpler formula.  I would be happy to be proved wrong, but honestly, that formula is pretty simple already.  :)